# Installing SDM on a Cisco 2821 ISR

Tags: cisco

I trying to change the configuration of our router, it's a Cisco 2821 Integrated Services Router.  I don't know much about Cisco products.  While looking at the PDF manual for the router I notices it talked about SDM Security Device Manager.  But when I point my web browser at the IP address of the router, it give me a very simple web interface.  It's sort of like a string builder for CLI commands.  I'm guessing SDM was not installed on it.  So my question how would I go about do that?

I found this link (below), but I'm a bit new to networking.  So any advice would be welcome.
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/cisco_router_and_security_device_manager/software/quick/guide/SDMq7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy answer: Don't.

SDM is ace for configuring firewalls, but kinda sucks, IMO, on routing hardware.  Ciscos are a lot easier to manage with the CLI than any hacked together GUI.  They're not easy, but if you wanted an easy router, you've picked the wrong one from the word go.

Pick up a decent book on IOS, and you won't regret it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  SDM is end-of-life:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps5318/eol_c51-620445.html

You might want to try Cisco Configuration Professional as a replacement:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9422/index.html

Comment: @Tom  Are you saying the router is bad or just SDM?

Comment: The router's fine.. SDM, is a pile of wank.

Comment: @SamSanders The router's a lovely platform, actually.